# Using WbExport and WbInclude Commands in SQL Workbench Batch Mode

Tags: sql, sql-workbench-j

I'm operating on a Windows Machine, trying to export the results of a query by running SQL Workbench in Batch mode.  After reading the SQL Workbench documentation, it sounds like **WbExport** is the best command for exporting results from a query.

Another requirement is the query I want to run is in an external .sql file.  Again, according the SQL documentation, in batch mode, I can either use the **WbInclude** command or **-script** parameter to run a query from an external .sql file.  However, I'm not able to get either of these to work correctly with **WbExport**.  I've tried running SQL Workbench in Batch mode using both sqlwbconsole64.exe and sqlworkbench.jar.  Please see the four examples below:

```
java -jar sqlworkbench.jar -profile='connection-profile' -command='WbExport -file=test_export.txt -type=text -delimiter=\t; WbInclude test.sql;'

java -jar sqlworkbench.jar -profile='connection-profile' -command='WbExport -file=test_export.txt -type=text -delimiter=\t' -script='test.sql'

sqlwbconsole64 -profile='connection-profile' -command='WbExport -file=test_export.txt -type=text -delimiter=\t; WBInclude test.sql;'

sqlwbconsole64 -profile='connection-profile' -command='WbExport -file=test_export.txt -type=text -delimiter=\t' -script='test.sql'
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not use `WbInclude` as the "source" for the WbExport command. You need to put everything into a single SQL script:

File `export.sql`:

```
WbExport -file=test_export.txt -type=text -delimiter=\t;
select * 
from the_table;
```

Or if you just want to export a single table, use:

```
WbExport -file=test_export.txt -type=text -delimiter=\t -sourceTable=the_table;
```

Then run

```
java -jar sqlworkbench.jar -profile='connection-profile' -script=export.sql
```

(Btw: if `-script` is specified, `-command` is ignored)

Comment: SQLWorkbench/J is cool even with it's limited scripting capabilities, but unfortunately there is no good examples and you literally should experiments a lot to get even simple scripts running in a batch mode...